# how to fix the connection (SQL server, C# form) if it gave an unhandled exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, exception

i developed an application in C# "windows form", i want it to save the data into a sql server database, so i

1. create a class that can assure the connection with the data base by an insert function ,
2. i wrote the connectstring in the App.config file,
3. a save button in the form can save the data into each class from the input fields and call the function (step 1) insert

by the try-catch i notice that i have a problem in the connection class and i tried to fix it but i couldn't, "it doesn't give any error" 
please if some one have any idea about this i need some help!

```cs
public class classeConnect
{

    // connection to the database
    static string MyConnStrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstrng"].ConnectionString;

    // methode pour insérer les données dans la base de données
    #region insertion des données
    // insertion des données
    public static bool dataInsert(Visiteur c, Adresse a, LDateTime d, Analytics an, Deal dl)
    {
        // creation d'un return default 
        bool IsSuccess = false;

        // connection avec la base de données
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyConnStrng);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            // la requête SQL pour insertion des données

            // table Visiteur
            string sql1 = "INSERT INTO Visiteur (Nom_Visiteur, Prénom_Visiteur, EmailAdresse, CellPhoneNumber) VALUES (@Nom_Visiteur, @Prénom_Visiteur, @EmailAdresse, @CellPhoneNumber)";

            // table Location
            string sql2 = "INSERT INTO Location (Adresse, TypeHabitation, Propreté) VALUES (@Adresse, @TypeHabitation, @Propreté)";

            // table DateVisit
            string sql3 = "INSERT INTO DateVisite (Année, Mois, Jours, Heurs) VALUES (@Année, @Mois, @Jours, @Heurs)";

            // table Analytics
            string sql4 = "INSERT INTO Analytics (TypeAuto, TypeVetement, FamilleEntiere, HowHeardOfUs) VALUES (@TypeAuto, @TypeVetement, @FamilleEntiere, @HowHeardOfUs)";

            // table deal
            string sql5 = "INSERT INTO Deal (ProduitChoisit, FreinMotiveAchat, Broadcast) VALUES (@ProduitChoisit, @FreinMotiveAchat, @Broadcast)";

            // creation des commandes SQL
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sql3, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand(sql4, conn);
            SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand(sql5, conn);


            // creation du parameter add data

            // parametrs table visiteur
            #region parametrs table visiteur
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nom_Visiteur", c.NomVisiteur);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prénom_Visiteur", c.PrénomVisiteur);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdresse", c.EmailAdresse);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CellPhoneNumber", c.CellPhoneNumber);
            #endregion

            // parametrs table location
            #region parametrs table location
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adresse", a.AdresseVisiteur);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeHabitation", a.TypeHabitation);
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Propreté", a.Propreté);
            #endregion

            // parametrs table DateVisite
            #region parametrs table DateVisite
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Année", d.Année);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mois", d.Mois);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jours", d.Jours);
            cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heurs", d.Heurs);
            #endregion

            // parametrs table Analytics
            #region parametrs table Analytics
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeAuto", an.TypeAuto);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TypeVetement", an.TypeVetement);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilleEntiere", an.FamilleEntiere);
            cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HowHeardOfUs", an.HowKnowUs);
            #endregion

            // parametrs table Deal
            #region parametrs table Analytics
            cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProduitChoisit", dl.ProduitChoisit);
            cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FreinMotiveAchat", dl.FreinAchat);
            cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broadcast", dl.Broadcast);
            #endregion

            //ouverture de la connection avec la base de données


            #region table visiteur
            int rows1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows1 > 0)
            {
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            #endregion
            #region table Location
            int rows2 = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows2 > 0)
            {
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            #endregion
            #region table DateVisit
            int rows3 = cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows3 > 0)
            {
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            #endregion
            #region table Analytics
            int rows4 = cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows4 > 0)
            {
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            #endregion
            #region table Deal
            int rows5 = cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows5 > 0)
            {
                IsSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsSuccess = false;
            }
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return IsSuccess;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: If it enters a `catch` block then your code has thrown an exception. Set a breakpoint in your catch block and look at the exception that's being thrown.

Comment: Could you please check if C# is OK with non ASCII propertiy names like for examle: "dl.Année", "dl.Propreté", "dl.PrénomVisiteur", because the StackOverflow highlighting certainly isnt. 

If changing them to ASCII chars doesnt help could you please try to diagnose where your Code goes south the way @Diado proposed.

Comment: You can also break into the debugger by changing exception settings. In Visual Studio, "Debug" menu => "Windows" submenu => "Exception Settings" you can set it to break on all Common Language Runtime exceptions. This will stop on the line of code where the exception is thrown.

Comment: thank for every one ho helped me in this i solved this problem it was in the connection strings i copy it from the connectionstringd website